# Why is iOS sending memory warning to deallocated objects, causing my app to crash?

Tags: ios, ios8, unrecognized-selector, didreceivememorywarning

I was searching crash logs of my app, and I've seen this (which occured quiet a few times, not just once or twice):

[image]

As seen above, notification center posted a memory warning notification, and it was somehow forwarded to a `CALayer`. I've also seen instances of `didReceiveMemoryWarning:` messages sent to other deallocated objects such as `UIImageView`s or even private `_UINavigationBarBackground` objects, when zombies were enabled on my debugger, too, crashing my app. Why would this happen?

Comment: i have the same issue with core foundation and i learnt about that we have to manually release CF objects in ARC so i don't know about your issue but i can say that ARC not automatically release CF memories but not confirm that your crash in CALayer hope this helps you.

Comment: @JAYRAPARKA if you retain it yourself, yes you'll need to release it. but this isn't about it. even if it was leaking memory, under no circumstances the system should send a memory warning to an object that can't recognize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSNotificationCenter only keeps *weak* references to observers.

What's probably happening is that you have one ore more objects somewhere that register for UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification, but which never unregister (thats a bug). Since NSNotificationCenter only keeps weak references to those objects it doesn't notice when they are dealloc'd and their memory is reused for other objects such as CALayer etc, which do not implement a method named didReceiveMemoryWarning.

Comment: One of my custom classes was registering for that very notification, but never unregistering. I've unregistered them on dealloc and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a memory management issue. Typically, the memory warning would be sent to a currently-existing `UIViewController`, which lives at some hypothetical location X in memory.

But at runtime, instead of finding your `UIViewController` at location X as expected, it found some other object, like a random `CALayer` or `UIImageView`, which does not know how to respond to `didReceiveMemoryWarning:`. This results in the crash you're seeing.

Does your project use ARC? Enable it if its not already, that should reduce the frequency of these errors. If you're using manual retain/release, it is likely there is some error in your implementation.

If you have any code that does funny things with memory, or any code that does hacky things with view controller transitions, those are possible culprits, I'd post that code.

Also, try manually sending a memory warning to your app as soon as it is done starting up, to see if the issue manifests immediately, or if the app needs to run for a while before it occurs.